# How to print a specific extent of an ArcGis Map?

Tags: gis, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to print a specific zone on an Arcgis maps with the JS API (not the extend that is displayed).

I didn't find any method or option to do this so I tried to change the extend and then print the map :

```
var extent = new esri.geometry.Extent(
    -620526.0922336339, 
    5993991.149960931, 
    108988.90572005256, 
    6293624.300838808, 
    myMap.spatialReference
);

myMap.setExtent(extent, true).then(function() {
    console.log('setExtend is finished');

    var template = new esri.tasks.PrintTemplate();
    template.exportOptions = {
        width : 500,
        height : 500
    };
    template.format = 'jpg';
    template.layout = 'MAP_ONLY';

    var params = new esri.tasks.PrintParameters();
    params.map = myMap;
    params.template = template;

    var printTask = new esri.tasks.PrintTask(urlToThePrintServer);
    printTask.execute(params);
});
```

Since setExtent is asynchonous and return a defered I have to use the 'then' method.

I can see the map moving but the defered doesn't seem to works ... (I don't see the console.log()).

- is there another way to print a specific extend of a map ?
- if not why is the 'then' method never called ?

(I'm using the 3.12 JS API)

Comment: The look does not look bad, apart of the fact that you're using the deprecated non-AMD style. Did you try setting a breakpoint inside that function ?

Comment: yes, I also added a try/catch. There is no error, but the 'then' part is never called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good to me, though obviously you didn't post all your JavaScript or any of your HTML. Maybe you're not requiring the modules you need. Or maybe your code is trying to run before the map is loaded, though that's unlikely because as you say, the map does move. Or maybe something else is wrong.

I put a full working example at http://jsfiddle.net/06jtccx0/ . Hopefully you can compare that to what you're doing and figure out what is wrong with your code. Here's the same code for your convenience:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      body {
        background-color: #FFF;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/"></script>
    <script>
      var myMap;
      var urlToThePrintServer = "http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task";

      require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
        myMap = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "topo",  //For full list of pre-defined basemaps, navigate to http://arcg.is/1JVo6Wd
          center: [-122.45, 37.75], // longitude, latitude
          zoom: 13
        });
        myMap.on("load", function(map) {
          var extent = new esri.geometry.Extent(
              -620526.0922336339, 
              5993991.149960931, 
              108988.90572005256, 
              6293624.300838808, 
              myMap.spatialReference
          );

          myMap.setExtent(extent, true).then(function() {
            console.log('setExtend is finished');
            require([
                "esri/tasks/PrintTemplate",
                "esri/tasks/PrintParameters",
                "esri/tasks/PrintTask"
                ], function(
                  PrintTemplate,
                  PrintParameters,
                  PrintTask
                  ) {

              var template = new PrintTemplate();
              template.exportOptions = {
                  width : 500,
                  height : 500
              };
              template.format = 'jpg';
              template.layout = 'MAP_ONLY';

              var params = new PrintParameters();
              params.map = myMap;
              params.template = template;

              var printTask = new PrintTask(urlToThePrintServer);
              printTask.execute(params, function(response) {
                console.log("The printed document is at " + response.url);
                window.open(response.url);
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the only difference between your code and mine is that all the code is called when I clicked on a button and that my map have several layers ....

Comment: I replaced my dojo.addOnLoad() by the require like you did on your example and removed all my layers and it is working now ...

Comment: Your fiddle code was a great help.  In my app I created a map for printing and just hid it so my print outs are independent of the viewable map extent.